# How do I create pointed stroke end caps in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, graphic-styles

I'm sort of new to Illustrator, can someone explain how the pointed strokes on the image below are done?

[image]

Comment: Not much to go on here.. ermm.. remove the stroke profile maybe?

Comment: @Royale Designs Does the circled area contain something that you want to replicate or does it contain something unwanted that you want to get rid of? Flatten can be both of them. The gradual thinning can be inserted to a stroke with the Width tool.

Comment: @user287001 yes I want to replicate that

Comment: Then try the Width tool to a stroke.

Comment: @user287001 Ok thanks it worked! Thanks again!

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear. If you feel my edits were incorrect, please [edit again](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/137339/edit) and correct. Thanks! The word "flatten" in the title threw me off. I can see now, how you meant it, but it wasn't clear before. At least to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **Width Tool** or the **Profile** option on the **Stroke Panel** to make strokes taper at the ends.