# Illustrator how to make object ends sharp and free hand like?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have been looking for a way to make object ends sharp but can't find a decent method. So far I have discovered that I can make sharp ends on lines with strokes.

This is the object I want to use it on

[image]

This is what I want to apply on those circles

[image]

Comment: Hi. Have you tried using a [variable width profile](https://imgur.com/rgC9I2K) for the stroke?

Comment: Duplicate? https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/137339/how-do-i-create-pointed-stroke-end-caps-in-illustrator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merely change the **Profile** for the stroke on the **Stroke Panel**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But as I put outline stroke on this object I can't use it for some reason. https://imgur.com/a/IleRXwd

Comment: @in2d Don't outline the stroke. Width profiles only work on *strokes* not filled shapes. If you want to do this to a *shape*, you need to do it *manually*. There's no "quick setting" for such a thing for a filled shape.

Comment: You ONLY outline the stroke AFTER all the effects have been applied to the stroke.